# unable to open Eclipse even after specifying environment variable

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed eclipse Neon.
But when i clicked on it to open, It is not opening.
I even have set the Path in Environment Variables.

Comment: On what operating system? Do you get any errors at all? Have you rebooted?

Comment: Any errors happening at all?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is defined and %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in your system path. You can verify that by opening a command prompt, navigate to your eclipse folder and typing

`java -version`

If that commands returns the java version then everything should be fine.

Also, check if eclipse is using the right version of JDK/JRE. A 32 bit installation of eclipse would require a 32 bit JDK/JRE and vice versa for 64 bit editions. If that does not solve the issue check for messages in your Eclipse logs in your workspace:

`${workspace}/.metadata/.log`

You can also redirect any error messages to your console using the `-consoleLog` startup option.

Also check if there is any error initializing the java heap. If that's the case there should be at least one `hs_err_pidXXXXX.log` file generated in your eclipse folder.